# How to say this in correct Spanish "This is not the official page, just a fanpage"

Tags: traducción

I want to translate the following sentence into correct Spanish.

> This is not the trainer's official page, only a fanpage.

Would this be a correct translation: 'Esta no es la página oficial del entrenador/míster, solamente una página de fans'.

Are there any other ways I can say this? Please give me examples. My grammar is the problem: *Esta/esta*, *solo/solamente*, and word placement.

Answer (score 3):

En México suena mejor:

> Esta no es la página oficial del entrenador, es una página de fans.

Comment: En Chile también preferimos _fans_ a _admiradores_ o _aficionados_.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct, other way to say it could be:

> Esta no se trata de la página oficial, esta es la página de
> admiradores del entrenador.
>
> Esta es una página de aficionados no se trata de la página oficial del
> entrenador.

If you want to say it in another way try change the synonyms of 'fans'.

If `entrenador/míster` means that you want to put `míster` in the phrase please dont do that, this is not a correct word for `trainer` in spanish.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Míster is a very common used word for coach. Saying entrenador somewhat blunt. Any idea how I can use the word míster instead? Just replace it? Would that be correct?

Comment: If you want to use 'míster' in spanish there is no use for that word, some synonyms for trainer/coach could be `adiestrador, amaestrador, preparador, entrenador, director`

Comment: Dylan71: [*Míster*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PPNOWrd) is a Spanish word, and a widely used one at that; but it's pretty much restricted to a football trainer. If you're not talking about football, then maybe *entrenador* is probably a better term. BTW, these are alternative wordings; your original sentence was also fine. And "solamente" and "solo" are interchangeable when they work as an adverb.

Comment: As far as I know, *míster* is only used in Spain with this meaning. Nowadays, mainly as a synonym, but the main word is indeed *entrenador*.

Comment: @Gorpik Ah, the dialectical differences strike again! Yes, *míster* is used in Spain. I didn't know it was used exclusively here, though. However, I find it kind of dismissive to say "it's not a correct word". It is an intelligent thing to advise against using it as it may not be well received in most dialects, but it certainly isn't *incorrect.*

Comment: @Yay Some people have suggested that the DRAE should include a mark for words used only in Spain, as it has for words used only in certain other countries or in certain regions. This is a case where this mark would be useful. The word comes from 50 or 60 years ago, when a lot of English coaches came to work for Spanish football teams. Being English, the coach would be *mister* This or *mister* That, and the players started addressing them as just *mister*, as they would call a Spanish coach *señor*. And the word stuck as a synonym for *entrenador*.

Comment: @Yay I played sports (not soccer) in Spain for two years and never came across it, so I think it's definitely very particular to soccer. The only time I came across *míster* was a street *Mister Lodge* named after a diplomat.